# Can't create a GitHub repo with the name I want

Tags: github

I'm totally new at GitHub.com. I'm doing a Coursera Data Science Speicialization and as part of the course we need to create a new GitHub repo.

I have a free GitHub account there. 
I use Mac OS X 10.8, MacBook Air 2012.

My problem is when I go to https://github.com/new and try to create a new public repo, I start typing the name I want (e.g. test-repo), and I choose 'Public' and I check 'Initialize this repository with a README', but the green create repository button immediately turns dim and thus it doesn't allow me to create my repo.

As you also know, there's the line "Great repository names are short and memorable. Need inspiration? How about hairy-shame.". The trick is, when I choose the name from the 'Need inspiration?' line, it works perfectly well !! And every time I go to github.com to create a new repo, I can create one only with the name suggested by the "Need inspiration" line.

What shall I do to create a repo with the name that I want?

Comment: Hi, are you totally sure that the repository not yet exists under your username yet? Can you please post your github username, so I can take a look?

Comment: @gyurisc

Hi! Here's my profile:
https://github.com/alekscooper

But the thing is, that the next day everything started to work miraculously fine and now I can create any repo I want. I don't know what happened because neither my profile nor my computer had undergone any changes since the initial malfunctioning of GitHub.

And yes, that repo couldn't exist because there was nothing under my username.

Comment: Yes, I am. Anyway, it all worked fine the following day.

Answer (score 0):

If your repo doesn't exists yet, then it can be a glitch in the GUI:

Try removing the last letter of your repo name, and add that same latter again.
Chances are: the "Create Repository" button will be active.